# Is it possible to produce a model for this shadow-play character?

Tags: modeling

From all the tutorial videos I have seen so far, we will need at least a front view and a side view to properly model a character. For example, like shown in this tutorial (please fast forward to 12:43ish):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0QT1GNMevfc

What I want to achieve is:

- Model a character that is from a traditional Chinese shadow-play. A character like this one shown below:

[image]

Technically, those models are **almost** two-dimensional. If I model those shadow-play characters in 2D, it will not be possible to have this kind of turning effect (please refer to the following video, please freeze it at exactly 0:33).

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GcYdgudn83M

I am thinking:

- is it possible to model those shadow-play characters as if they are made of thick papers, e.g. almost 2D but there is a bit thickness in them. Then this turning effect can be achieved.

Please feel free to suggest otherwise.

Comment: I've seen the video, imho you just need to use orthographic camera, and place (even flat) 2d objects onb different depth levels, as you would do with paper...

Comment: You can right-click on a Youtube video and copy a link at the current time. That way you can provide links to people without telling them to go to a certain time.

Answer (score 3):

Create the model flat (so as a 2D model), then apply the [Solidify Modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/generate/solidify.html) to give it thickness. That'll make it easy to have a uniform thickness without having to extrude all surfaces manually.